# Include enum from domain to gwt shared classes

Tags: java, gwt, enums

I have project with structure like

```
+com.example
     +domain
          +enums
     +gwt
          +client
          +server
          +shared
```

my gwt config

```
<source path='client'/>
<source path='shared'/>
<entry-point class="com.example.gwt.client.Dashboard"/>
```

What I really wan't is to use my domain enums at client side. Or I must duplicate them as shared classes/convert to Strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the enum classes are GWT-compatible, you could place an `Enums.gwt.xml` in `domain/enums` with a `<source path='' />` tag.  Your main `gwt.xml` file would need to add an `<inherits>` tag to pull in `Enums.gwt.xml`.  Also, the `<source>` tags can be [filtered](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuidePathFiltering) if you need finer-grained control.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Is there any way to do this without putting gwt specific classes into my domain package? I guess splitting project into several modules would help, wouldn't it?